# Is it possible to multiply look up column values - sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is possible to multiply the look up value columns in workflow? Can anybody please tell me?

I have a custom list in which I have two two look up columns, I need to set a work flow that should multiply the 2 lookup column values and display the value in the next column

Could somebody please help me soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SharePoint Designer 2013 you have the "Do Calculation" action which takes two variables (your two lookup values), makes a calculation (minus, plus, multiplied etc) and outputs the result to a new variable. Then you can use this variable for whatever you want to do, send it in an e-mail, update a list item or perhaps just log it in the workflow history.

Hope that helps

Comment: Btw, it is no problem to use SharePoint Designer 2013 when creating workflows for SharePoint 2010

Comment: Dear Mange, Thank you very much for answering, let me check with your suggestion.